# How to make graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm not good at matplotlib, I need your help, I have an upload of this format by year from 2015-2022:

```
PHP:282
JavaScript:273
HTML:229
HTML5:227
MySQL:218
CSS:217
CSS3:203
PHP5:184
jQuery:168
1С:168
```

I need to do something like a visual graph - from the bottom - the year, on the left - the number of mentions (indicated next to above in the code(the numbers), as well as a legend on the top left: color - tag( for example - PHP - green, CSS3 - blue....)

Again, X - years, Y - the values of teg using: PHP: ---> (282 this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you provide no information on the years, I can only assume that these mentions are total mentions between 2015 and 2022.

In that case, I would recommend `catplot` from `seaborn`. This will plot the "tags" (as you call them) on the X-axis and the mentions (counts) on the Y-axis. You would then change the X-label name to reflect what the X-axis refers to, i.e., mentions between 2015 and 2022. Your code would look like this (taking only the first two data points as an example):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tags':['PHP', 'JavaScript'], 'Mentions':[282, 273]}) 

sns.catplot(data = df, x = 'Tags', y = 'Mentions', kind = 'bar').set_xlabels('Number of mentions from 2015-2022')
```

Comment: Labels for x need's to be like 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2020 ...

Comment: In that case, you would need to have three columns: Year, Tags, and Mentions. You would then write `x = 'Year'` and then add the argument "hue = 'Tags' to `catplot` to get the output that you want. But, like I said in the answer, you would need to have data for mentions per year, which you do not provide in your question.